# Is there a way to name only certain columns in Pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I know it's possible to name columns when using `DataFrame.read_csv()` in pandas by passing the optional `names = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', ...]` parameter. However, my question is can you name only the first X columns and the rest get autonamed?

Basically, I have a csv with 23 columns that I want to name, and a further 1023 columns that I need to keep in the DataFrame but don't care about what they're called. Here's an image to illustrate the requirement:

[image: DataFrame showing columns requiring renaming]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a setting in pandas to do this, so I just generated a list of column column names and rename the columns in the DataFrame.

This will work even if you don't know how many columns to expect at the end

### Dynamically Rename Columns in Data Frame

```
import pandas

#Read file
myFile =  pandas.read_csv("C:\\python_work_area\\TestFile.csv",header=None)

#Set known column names
arr_colName = ["MyColName1","MyColName2","MyColName3"]

numOfUnkownCols = len(myFile.columns) - len(arr_colName)
#Generate array of numbers, 1 for each unknown column. Could hard code numOfUnkownCols if column count is known
arr_nums = list(range(1,numOfUnkownCols+1))

#Add numbered unnamed column names to arr_colName
for i in arr_nums:
    arr_colName.append("UnnamedColumn" + str(i))

#Rename column names. inplace = true renames the columns in the existing object, rather than generating a copy 
myFile.set_axis(arr_colName, axis=1, inplace=True)
print (myFile)
```